# Ada: prefix of "image" attribute must be a type

Tags: ada

I'm trying to use Ada to print a class derived from Natural; however, I keep getting the error, `prefix of "image" attribute must be a type`. Google apparently knows nothing useful about this error.

Here is the simplified code which produced this error:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Layout; use Layout;
procedure temptest is
   term : Terminator_ID;
   begin
      term := Layout.Block_GetOpposite (1, Layout.REVERSED);
   Put_Line (Item => term'Image);
   end temptest;
```

Here is the definition of `Terminator_ID` in my `Layout` package:`type Terminator_ID is new Natural range 1 .. 40;`

What is causing this error and what is the appropriate way to correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the syntax for converting a number to string is `Type_Name'Image(var_containing_value)`.

I changed my code to:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
with Layout; use Layout;
procedure temptest is
   term : Terminator_ID;
   begin
      term := Layout.Block_GetOpposite (1, Layout.REVERSED);
   Put_Line (Item => Terminator_ID'Image (term));
   end temptest;
```

and it compiles fine now.

Comment: I was/is written it out in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left out a word in my previous comment. I meant to write "Which *is* exactly what the error message was telling you".

Comment: GNAT has an implementation-defined attribute `'Img` which does what you wanted.

Comment: @KeithThompson, unfortunately there's a large gap between that error message and the syntax it wanted. And I wasn't able to find documentation for the error online. Hence my question.

Comment: @weberc2 actually error message wrote enough information, and you could search in ARM for Image attribute.

Comment: @darkestkhan actually it didn't (not enough to shrink the gap). Not everything that's readily evident to Ada experts is accordingly evident to those of us who're only trained in lesser languages. For instance, the fact that an attribute (called "Image" nonetheless) takes a parameter and returns a string is rather bizarre. I'm sure there's a great reason as to why, but like I said, to those of us who aren't Ada legends, the information is lacking.

Comment: @weberc2 actually it isn't that bizarre - many attributes take argument (for example: Length, Range, Image, Output, Input, Read, Write). And idk what Ada legend is, but it certainly isn't me.

Comment: @darkestkhan All of the examples you mentioned are Ada-exclusive, which reinforces my point that Ada is counter-intuitive (I can't think of any standard languages that consider an attribute to be a function). Only an Ada programmer would think "I need a string? I had better search the ARM for an attribute called 'Image' to get the proper syntax". The rest of us probably wouldn't expect a type to have an "Image" attribute that behaves like a procedure and returns a string.

Comment: @weberc2 That is because Image is type attribute so it is taking the argument and behaving like (pure) function. I don't know of any standard language that has attributes like Ada (the closest you get are methods on objects but that is not equivalent of attributes).

Comment: @darkestkhan Exactly. Which is why it is so bizarre, and why it is so hard to find information from the ARM. That is, because much of the information in the ARM is referenced in such a way that it is only useful to those who already know Ada. The rest of us would never think to search ARM for "Image attribute", we would search it for "How to get the string representation of a number".

Comment: @weberc2 Protip: you have list of all language defined attributes in Annex K of ARM :) Many of them with usage examples.

Comment: @darkestkhan That's good to know; however, for the sake of every sorry soul that has to learn Ada, I'll continue to ask questions on Stack Overflow so there will be a more user-friendly, accessible, and generally useful source of information available. Who knows, people may actually start using it for fun projects if good Internet resources are made available?